I2C_SCL_SDA_Low level voltage issue
We have issue with I2C rise time during 1MHz of data transmission on the device side.
We have tuned Rp2 pull value to 1k and 2.2K still the issue remain same.
If reduce the pullup value the rise time will be near to the standard value but not the same, but in this scenario VL level is going high.
Is there any other way to match the rise time as per the standard value i.e for 1MHz is 120ns?


Welcome.  Providing traces of the problem would be very helpful, as would details of the physical layout (in particular the capacitance) of the two buses.  If you do a search on the site for similar questions, you'll find there are many about I2C rise time, and the answers will almost all point you at the question of capacitance.
